# How to use Jetty Jspc Maven Plugin for Tomcat 7

Tags: jetty

I use the Jetty Jspc Maven Plugin 9.3.11 as per https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-jspc-maven-plugin.html. The compiled JSPs fail to run due to

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceImports

`JspSourceImports` is an interface introduced with Tomcat 8 and hence not available on Tomcat 7. The Jetty Jspc Maven Plugin doesn't allow me to configure against which Tomcat/JSP version to compile.

I assume that implicitly comes with the specific version of the plugin. So, the question is how to use the Jetty Jspc Maven Plugin for Tomcat 7?

Comment: Cross-link to the mailing list msg: http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg07303.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seems to be exactly as anticipated in my comment above:

```xml
<plugin>
  <!-- https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/jetty-jspc-maven-plugin.html -->
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-jspc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${jetty-jspc-plugin.version}</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>jspc</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>jspc</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

`${tomcat.version}` is some version from the 7.x branch. There's no need to have it match the runtime version exactly, just needs to be API-compatible.

Answer (score 1):

If older JSP support is what's required, could you use the older Jetty 8 jspc plugin?

> Note: Jetty 8 is EOL (End of Life) now, and it used the Glassfish Jasper 2.2.2 JSP engine (which has been completely deprecated and replaced with Apache Jasper 8.5.4 in Jetty 9)

So for Jetty 8, you'll be at:

- JSP 2.2
- JSTL 1.2

See: [org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-jspc-maven-plugin:8.1.16.v20140903](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.mortbay.jetty%7Cjetty-jspc-maven-plugin%7C8.1.16.v20140903%7Cmaven-plugin)

Comment: Could I use the `jspc` plugin parameter to point to a Tomcat 7 `JspC.class` (i.e. from a Tomcat 7 `jasper.jar`)? I'd have to have a way to tell the plugin to prefer the externally supplied `JspC.class`, I'd add a dependency to tomcat-jasper:7.0.70 to the plugin.